# Spring batch: several hosts, one database

Tags: spring-batch

My question is simple - is spring batch made in the way that it allows batch processing hosts to be connected to the same database which contains all spring batch's tables like `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION`, `BATCH_JOB_STATUS` etc?

I'm asking because now I have application organized in this way and I have DB deadlocks on those tables...

Comment: Yes.  What database are you using?

Comment: Oracle. I have a situation that one host starts job, somehow hangs, and job remains in status `STARTED`. then as other people suggested i need to update this record manually to status `FAILED`

Comment: I'd need to see how the connection pool is configured as well as the stack trace if you get one.

Comment: Default configuration from spring boot. only driver class, url and credentials are specified. Unfortunately there is no stacktrace - that looks really like deadlock. While it's hanging - I can't update/delete any record with direct connection to the database.

Comment: Have you done a thread dump?  What's the deadlock actually on?

Comment: No, need actually to do it, thanks for hint!